# ssh with identical machines

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I have two identical beaglebones that I'm working with. They have the same hostname and originally had the same IP, though I changed one to see if that made a difference. They're going to be deployed to 2 different networks.

My problem is I lost the ability to ssh into both of them. The password has not been changed and I can log in from my wife's computer, but on mine I get:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

finally followed by

```
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

This wasn't a problem until I set up static IPs on them. What have I done/what can I do to fix it?

I'm running Ubuntu on both the beaglebones and my computer.

Comment: Have you tried getting onto the server via the console and looking at the logs?

Comment: Please post the output of `ssh -v $IP` (possibly with any other options needed; the `-v` is the important part)

Comment: Unfortunately, I was on a short timeline and both units had to be installed. I have a clone of the SD card, so I will be able to test this again soon. The only other thing to add is that as soon as I switched them back to DHCP, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Logs are the very first place to start.

Failing that, run sshd in debug mode on the server and see what it says:

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -Dd
```

Answer (score 0):

Simular to what @fukwai2 said. I would recommend starting ssh on another port on the same machine.

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 2222 -v
```

When you run the client try with the -v flag to see if you can also get any more output.

Lastly just out of experience look at everything the output says even if you think its wrong because it has not changed sometimes you forget you did something.